# What does Bachelard mean by "Applied Rationalism"?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, terminology, rationalism

I've heard this term many times. I've tried to google it but there is a very little about it. There is no online resource which explains the term and what is this position.

So my question is, What is applied rationalism? Can any one explain it?

Comment: See also [here](http://www.radicalphilosophy.com/wp-content/files_mf/rp173article3tilesbachelardrationalismapplique.pdf) and Mary Tiles, *Technology, Science, and Inexact Knowledge: Bachelard’s Non-Cartesian Epistemology* into Gary Gutting (editor), [Continental Philosophy of Science](https://books.google.it/books?id=W6RVSDUG9acC&pg=PA157) (2008), page 157-on.

Answer (score 3):

See :

- Gaston Bachelard, [Le rationalisme appliqué](https://books.google.it/books?id=1s8KAAAAMAAJ) (1949 - 3rd ed : 1966) page 3-4.

He tries a "mediation" between *rationalism* and *empirism* :

> It is precisely in the *central* position that the dialectic of reason and technique finds its efficacity. We will try to place us in this central position where occur both an *applied rationalism* and an *educated materialism*. [...] It is through its applications that rationalism conquers its objective values. It is therefore no longer to judge scientific thought relying on formal, abstract, universal rationalism. We must reach a concrete rationalism, always founded on detailed and specific experiences. It also requires that this rationalism is *open* enough to receive from experience new determinations ["revised" Google translation].